# pivot_wider dynamically by number of ocurrences

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

Sorry if the title is not very descriptive. I have data like this:

[image: data]

What I am trying to do is pivot over `Product` and count the ocurrences of each type of `Client` they have, in order to dynamically add columns like "most frequent client", "second most frequent client", etc.

If we group by `Product` and `Client` and count, we see the ocurrences of each `Client` in each `Product`:

[image: data grouped]

From here my goal would be to get to something like this:

[image: goal]

So "number 1 client" for A is C1, for B is C2, etc. Again, the thing is this should be dynamic, as I don´t know beforehand how many *"nX_Client"* columns are going to be.

Breaking ties (for `Product` C there are 2 `Client` with 1 ocurrence each) can be done randomly, by alphabetical order or however you want. It´s not important for my use case.

**reprex**:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Size <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
Product <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")
Client <- c("C0", "C0", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C1", "C0", "C1")
df <- data.frame( ID, Size, Product, Client )

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Product, Client) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `count` number of rows for every `Product` and `Client` and sort them. Create a column names for each `Product` based on their frequency and cast the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Product, Client, sort = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(n = sprintf('n%d_client', row_number())) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = Client)

# Product n1_client n2_client
#  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    
#1 A       C1        C0       
#2 B       C2        C1       
#3 C       C0        C1
```